# How can I solve this differential equation, what type is it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How can I solve this differential equation, what type is it? $$(x^2+2x-2y)dx=dy$$

How can I find the integrating factor?

Comment: Meaning $\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=x^2+2x$? Linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HINT

If the equation is $$ (x^2+2x-2y)*dx=dy $$then you can rewrite it as $$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 2y = x^2 + 2x $$ Now, you find the integrating factor: $ \text{I.F. } = e^{\int 2 dx} = e^{2x} $

The result is given by: $$ y \cdot e^{2x} = \int{ (x^2 + 2x)e^{2x} dx} $$

Such equations are pretty common and [are called](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909473/how-can-i-solve-this-differential-equation-what-type-is-it/909475?noredirect=1#comment1876522_909475) first-order linear differential equations (Thanks to @bof for comment).

Comment: They are called first-order **linear** equations. Please add a constant of integration to the integral at the end.

Comment: @bof Thanks. I was searching for homogeneous equations :/ Doesn't the constant of integration come _after_ the integration is done?